# validating a field using zend from and validator in zend framework2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

i have a field name topic_name[] in my form the code of my form is below

```
   ?php

     namespace Tutorials\Form;

     use Zend\Captcha;
     use Zend\Form\Element;
     use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
     use Zend\Form\Form;
     use Zend\InputFilter\Input;
     use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

     class AddTopicForm extends Form {
         public $fieldData;

      public function __construct($data = array()){ 

          parent::__construct('AddTopic');
          $this->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal');
          $this->setAttribute('novalidate', 'novalidate');
          $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'topic_name[]',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'id' => 'topic_name',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'value' => ''
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => ' Topic Name',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
          'name' => 'id',
          'attributes' => array(
           'type'  => 'hidden',
           'id' => 'id'
        )
    ));

     $button = new Element('add_more');
     $button->setValue('+AddMore');
     $button->setAttributes(array(
             'type'  => 'button',
             'id'=>'add_more',
             'class'=>'btn btn-info'
         ));

     $save = new Element('save');
     $save->setValue('Save');
     $save->setAttributes(array(
             'type'  => 'submit',
             'id'=>'save',
             'class'=>'btn btn-info'
         ));


     $reset = new Element('reset');
     $reset->setValue('Reset');
     $reset->setAttributes(array(
             'type'  => 'reset',
             'id'=>'reset',
             'class'=>'btn'
         ));

       $this->add($button);
       $this->add($save);
       $this->add($reset);
     }//end of function_construct.
  }//end of registration form class.
```

After creating this form i am adding more field with jquery of the same topic_name[] and i am getting the data as below

In post values i am getting the values as below

```
   Array
     (
     [topic_name] => Array
       (
           [0] => gdfgdfg
           [1] => dfgdfg
           [2] => gfhg
           [3] => gfhfg
           [4] => jhgjhj
           [5] => hjhjgh
           [6] => jghjghj
        )

       [id] => 
       [save] => Save
    )
```

after that i am validating this data using validator

```
     <?php
       namespace Tutorials\Form;

       use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;   
       use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;                 
       use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;  
       use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;  
       use Zend\I18n\Validator\Alpha;

   class AddTopicFilterForm implements InputFilterAwareInterface  {
       protected $inputFilter;    
       public $fieldData;

   function __construct($data = array()) {
       if(!empty($data['data']['topic_name'])) {
        $this->fieldData = $data['data']['topic_name'];
       }
    }
     public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter){
        throw new \Exception("Not used");
     }

   public function getInputFilter(){
    if (!$this->inputFilter) {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $factory     = new InputFactory();
        //for($i = 0; $i < count($this->fieldData); $i++) {
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'topic_name[]',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'    => 'Alpha',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min'      => 1,
                            'max'      => 100,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )));
      //}
        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
       }

       return $this->inputFilter;
     }
  }
```

But i am getting no error as well as redirecting back to the form without any error message i know that it is not validating my data. I tried this through a loop but getting the error message of empty field.Does any one know how to validate my data as above??

I have another question that can i use [] in my filed name like topic_name[]?? i am asking this because i have tried validate this for single value but getting the same error message "Value is required and can't be empty"

Comment: I think you should look at `Zend\Form\Element\Collection`

Comment: I have read some where to validate this the use of callback but i am still in confusion to use that.Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Please take this constructively: that's an incredibly unsightly way to create forms.  Check out this how-to: http://circlical.com/blog/2015/7/6/zend-framework-2-forms-factories-inputfilters-and-hydration  Follow it closely, creating elements within init(), and binding input filters to forms in factories.

Comment: The given url  does not contain the array data validator for a specific field.